# AutoCompleteTextView: want to filter character that would be matched from the left

Tags: android

I am using AutoCompleteTextView in my android application. When typing character in textview then matched any positions character that is available in the list. But I want to filter character that would be matched from the left. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `contains()` method to compare. Use `indexOf()` method to check if it returns 0 or  regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
Following is my code:
**Layout:**
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/txtCustName" 
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLines="1" 
android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:dropDownSelector="#a0b4f0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

**Code:**
        AutoCompleteTextView txtCustName=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCustName);
        txtCustName.setAdapter(C.getArrayAdapter("Select CHEM_NAME||', '||Add1||'::'||CHEM_CODE from Chemist"));
```